# Divergent implicit expansion when abstracting over Traversable

Tags: scala, collections, implicit, scala-cats, circe

FINAL EDIT: All corner cases have been solved, the only issue is that I have to copy a private `Encoder.encodeTraversableOnce` method from Circe to get the `Encoder`'s working. I also had to change `MyCollection` to use `TraversableOnce` rather than just `Traversable` (this is because the `Encoder`'s only work with `TraversableOnce` where as the `Decoder` works with `Traversable`. The fiddle that demonstrates all of the cases can be found here https://scalafiddle.io/sf/F5Qo8cn/15.

Fiddle can be found here https://scalafiddle.io/sf/F5Qo8cn/8

Basically I am trying to abstract over a collection type, this is in context of models that contain traversable collections, i.e. assume we have the following

```
case class MyCollection[C[A] <: Traversable[A]](stuff: C[String])
```

This allows us to instantiate `MyCollection` with a specific collection type, i.e.

```
val innerV = MyCollection(Vector("a"))
val innerL = MyCollection(List("b"))
```

`MyCollection` will also happen to have a concrete type, so when we access the `.stuff` method it will return the type we use to create over it (i.e. in the case of `innerV` its `Vector` where as with `innerL` its `List`)

Since this is context of a web framework, `MyCollection` happens to represent some JSON, so using Circe 0.9.1 we can write a decoder as follows

```
object MyCollection {

  implicit def decoder[C[A] <: Traversable[A]]: Decoder[MyCollection[C]] = {
    new Decoder[MyCollection[C]] {
      override def apply(c: HCursor) = {
        c.downField("stuff").as[C[String]](Decoder.decodeTraversable[String, C](
          implicitly,
          implicitly
        ))
      }.map((x: C[String]) => MyCollection.apply(x))
    }
  }
}
```

Note that we are calling the `implicit` parameters explicitly as well as writing the decoder manually so that we can help track where the issue with implicits are. The idea is that we can generically instantiate a `case class` with any collection type we want, i.e.

```
def getMyCollection[C[A] <: Traversable[A]]: MyCollection[C] = {
  val jsonString = """{ "stuff": ["a","b"] }"""
  val json = io.circe.parser.parse(jsonString).right.get
  json.as[MyCollection[C]].right.get
}

def asVector: MyCollection[Vector] = getMyCollection[Vector]
def asList: MyCollection[List] = getMyCollection[List]
```

The issue is that I am getting a divergent implicit expansion, specifically on this line

```
c.downField("stuff").as[C[String]](Decoder.decodeTraversable[String, C](
  implicitly,
  implicitly // <- error happens here, this is a CBF implicit
))
```

The error we get is

> ScalaFiddle.scala:19: error: ambiguous implicit values:  both getter
>   StringCanBuildFrom in module class Predef of type =>
>   generic.this.CanBuildFrom[String,scala.this.Char,String]  and method
>   $conforms in module class Predef of type [A]=> $less$colon$less[A,A] 
>   match expected type T
>               implicitly
>               ^

Does anyone know what is causing this issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NB: Scala compiler option `-Xlog-implicits` can sometimes help you understand what is going on (although this case *is* quite strange!).

You don't have the implicit CBF in scope. You need to pass it from the top level, where concrete type of `C[_]` is known. So the fix is:

```
implicit def decoder[C[A] <: Traversable[A]](implicit cbf: CanBuildFrom[Nothing, String, C[String]]): Decoder[MyCollection[C]]
```

And if you remove `implicitly` statements, you would get a different error which should've hinted you that you are missing it.

```
Cannot construct a collection of type C[String] with elements of type String based on a collection of type Nothing.

not enough arguments for method decodeTraversable: (implicit decodeA: io.circe.Decoder[String], implicit cbf: scala.collection.generic.CanBuildFrom[Nothing,String,C[String]])io.circe.Decoder[C[String]].
Unspecified value parameter cbf.
```

---

The next part is mostly assumptions, so take it with a grain of salt. Maybe some Scala compiler hackers would correct me.

The answer to what triggers your error lies in where the `expected type T` comes from. `T` is not present as a type parameter in `Decoder`, nor in `CanBuildFrom`. But it is used in scala.Predef:

```
 @inline def implicitly[T](implicit e: T) = e
```

So when you're using `implicitly`, compiler can try two things:

- discover the instance of `CanBuildFrom` as dictated by `Decoder.decodeTraversable`
- (lower priority) discover *something* implicitly available and then try to find an implicit conversion to get a `CanBuildFrom`

The first step fails (there's no `CanBuildFrom`). But it's not over yet. So the compilers tries to find `implicit e: T` without any constraints on type T. And it finds multiple things:

- `StringCanBuildFrom`
- `$conforms`

So once it has found diverging implicits, it bails out immediately, giving you less than helpful error message.

With fix I propose using `implicitly` or not makes no difference, because it finishes at first step.

Comment: Thanks, this is definitely a very direct solution to my problem. I guess my only complaint is the fact that `getMyCollection` now has to know what the inner types of `MyCollection` and pass associated implicit `(implicit cbf: CanBuildFrom[Nothing, String, C[String]])` along everywhere.

Is there a nicer solution to this, such as maybe using a cats typeclass? i.e. maybe using `case class MyCollection[F: Foldable[_]](stuff: F[String])` that has better inference?

Comment: @mdedetrich I don't think there is. You can get away with combination of `Applicative[C]` (for `pure`) and `Monoid[C[String]]` or `MonoidK[C]` (for concat'ing and empty cases, but it is not directly supported by circe, so you'll have to do it by hand.

Comment: Sorry for bumping this but I actually realised that the above solution doesn't work for parameterized types, i.e. see https://scalafiddle.io/sf/F5Qo8cn/9

Comment: @mdedetrich you forgot to declare encoder & decoder as implicit. Also, contravariance won't work on fields, can be either covariant or invariant.

Comment: Okay, so I have finally figured out everything, sorry for the incorrect fiddle I pasted earlier. I was actually having issues with recursive datastructures. I managed to get everything to work, the only issue is that I basically have to copy a private encoder from Circe. Fiddle here is more self explanatory https://scalafiddle.io/sf/F5Qo8cn/15

Answer (score 2):

Your upper bound for `C` is too loose: inside the body of the method, the compiler knows nothing about `C` except that it is a `Traversable[A]`, and therefore it cannot automatically prove that there is an instance of `CanBuildFrom[Nothing, A, C[A]]`.

The easy workaround would be to supply the `CanBuildFrom[Nothing, A, C[A]]` from the outside, because those things are easy to generate on the use-site (because it obviously can be done for concrete implementations like `List` and `Vector`):

```
// Start writing your ScalaFiddle code here
import io.circe._
import io.circe.syntax._
import scala.collection.generic.CanBuildFrom

case class MyCollection[C[A] <: Traversable[A]](stuff: C[String])


val innerV = MyCollection(Vector("a")).stuff
val innerL = MyCollection(List("b")).stuff

object MyCollection {

  implicit def decoder[C[A] <: Traversable[A]]
    (implicit cbf: CanBuildFrom[Nothing, String, C[String]])
  : Decoder[MyCollection[C]] = {
    new Decoder[MyCollection[C]] {
      override def apply(c: HCursor) = {
        c.downField("stuff").as[C[String]](Decoder.decodeTraversable[String, C](
          implicitly,
          // this thing cannot be generated 
          // if you know nothing about `C` except
          // that it is a `Traversable[A]`
          cbf
        ))
      }.map((x: C[String]) => MyCollection.apply(x))
    }
  }
}

def getMyCollection[C[A] <: Traversable[A]]
  (implicit cbf: CanBuildFrom[Nothing, String, C[String]])
: MyCollection[C] = {
  val jsonString = """{ "stuff": ["a","b"] }"""
  val json = io.circe.parser.parse(jsonString).right.get
  json.as[MyCollection[C]].right.get
}

// cbf is supplied by compiler, it is trivial to
// generate here, because you know that you can do it
// for lists and vectors
def asVector: MyCollection[Vector] = getMyCollection[Vector] 
def asList: MyCollection[List] = getMyCollection[List] 

println(asVector)
println(asList)
```

**EDIT:** the proposal below cannot work, as @OlegPyzhcov has pointed out, because we don't have an instance of `GenTraversable` on which we could call `companion`. I'll leave it here, just in case that I suddenly remember what I was thinking.

> Another solution I can think of would be to tighten the upper bound to
>   `GenTraversable[A]`, and then go over the `companion` to
>   `GenericCompanion`, and build the required `CanBuildFrom[Nothing,
>   String, C[String]]` using the `newBuilder` method.
>
> The tradeoff would be: this would change the bound from
>   `Traversable[A]` to tighter `GenTraversable[A]`, but then you could
>   drop the annoying `cbf`-implicit.

Comment: The problem with 2nd solution is that when decoding JSON, there's not yet an instance to call `companion` on.

Comment: @OlegPyzhcov Ohh... Indeed. I was somehow stuck mentally in a datastructure-rewriting context, where a traversable has to be transformed into another traversable of same kind, but with different elements. This, of course, doesn't make any sense if there is no `Traversable` instance to begin with. Thanks, will fix it immediately.